# git: Find all uncommitted locals repos in a directory tree

Tags: git, scripting, file

I have a bunch(10-15) of local git repositories somewhere on my filesystem, but all in the folder /data/

I want to find all/any folder that has uncommitted changes. How can I do that? Kind of like a recursive global `git status` variant.

All the answers got it wrong I think. Any git command only works within the folder that's under git control. I need something to search for such folders.

So instead I wrote this script that does this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'find'
require 'fileutils'

#supply directory to search in as argument

@pat = ARGV[0]
(puts "directory argument required"; exit) unless @pat
Dir.chdir(@pat)
Find.find(@pat) do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    Dir.chdir(path)
    resp = `git status 2>&1`
    unless resp =~ /fatal|nothing to commit \(working directory clean\)/i
      puts "#{'#'*10}\n#{Dir.pwd}#{'#'*10}\n#{resp}"
      Find.prune
    end

    Dir.chdir(@pat)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 30):

Adapted from this gist on how to [print git status of all repositories under the current folder](https://gist.github.com/tafkey/664266c00387c98631b3):

```sh
find . -type d -name '.git' | while read dir ; do sh -c "cd $dir/../ && echo -e \"\nGIT STATUS IN ${dir//\.git/}\" && git status -s" ; done
```

The `find` command is your friend, along with some shell magic.

Comment: Digging up the past a little here, but could you add an explanation about how this works?

Comment: @GPPK Find all `.git` directories below current folder, pipe to while loop to get a named variable, `cd` to each `$dir` and echo its `git status` while also showing that directory

Comment: This is nice, but I'd add a `-maxdepth 2`, it's much faster. Final optimized command: `find . -type d -name '.git' -maxdepth 2 | while read dir ; do sh -c "cd $dir/../ && echo -e \"\nGIT STATUS IN ${dir//\.git/}\" && git status -s" ; done`

Answer (score 8):

There is also a shell script called [`multi-git-status`](https://github.com/fboender/multi-git-status) that does this.

Simply use the `mgitstatus` command (with an optional directory name argument):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't think git has this build in, thus I (also) created a script to do this: https://github.com/mnagel/clustergit

The problem with the snippets posted here is that they break as the output format of `git status` changes. My script has the same problem (as it basically works the same way), but at least you always get the latest version.
[image]

Comment: i like this script!

Comment: You can avoid breaking changes in the output of `git status` by using the `--porcelain` flag. See man pages for details.

Answer (score 6):

Something along these lines?

```
$ for i in /data/*/; do (cd $i && (echo $i; git status)); done
$ for i in /data/*/; do (cd $i \
> && (git status | grep -qx 'nothing to commit (working directory clean)' \
> || (echo $i && git status))); done
```

Comment: Don't use git-status. Use git-ls-files and git-diff / git-diff-files instead.

Comment: git-status is so called porcelain and it meant for user, and not for scripting. Its output can change without notice.

Comment: re: Jacob's terminology... [**What does the term “porcelain” mean in Git?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6976473/1366033)

Answer (score 5):

## Using only find

There's really no need for fancy bash tomfoolery, just use find.

```sh
find . -type d -name .git -print -execdir git status \;
```

- `find . -type d -name .git` recursively find all `.git` repositories
- `-print` print the path of the `.git` directory
- `-execdir git status \;` run `git status` in that diectory (the directory containing the git directory)

Answer (score 1):

```sh
for rp in /srv/*/
do
  printf '\ec'
  cd "$rp"
  git status
  echo "${rp%/}"
  read
done
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/5339520/scripts/git-status.sh)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the job for each repo

```
git status -uall
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status

Comment: That only does half of the job. The OP wants to run the status command for each repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[git ls-files](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html) --modified --deleted --exclude-standard" to list all modified and deleted files (`--exclude-standard` is not probably needed there, but just in case you want to list all unknown files that are not ignored with `--other`...). You can then check if the output of this command is empty.

Or you can check the exit status of "[git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) --quiet HEAD" if you want to check if "git commit -a" would pick up anything, or "git diff --cached --quiet HEAD" if you want to check if "git commit" would pick anything (or one of its plumbing relatives: `git-diff-files` or `git-diff-index`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not very fancy for formatting but how about something like

```
find . -iname ".git" -type d | sed -rne "s|(.+)/\.git|echo \1;cd \1;git status;cd /data|p" | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a pretty old thread now but in Windows 10 I couldn't get the WHILE/DO loop from @Tasos solution to work so I converted it to PowerShell.

This version also prints out the status of each uncommitted change as well as a bit of formatting for readability to group by folder names.

```powershell
cd C:\Projects

$msgs = @()
gci ".git" -Directory -Recurse -Hidden | % {
    $dir = $_
    cd $dir\..

    $gitMsgs = (git status -s)
    if ( $gitMsgs ) {
        $msgs += "$dir ****************************"
        $msgs += $gitMsgs
        $msgs += ""
    } 
}
$msgs | % { Write-Host $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

cargo install fd-find
https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#installation

```sh
find_nonclean_git () {
    fd -E Trash -H '^\.git$' ~ -x echo '{//}' | while read dir; do
        cd $dir
        echo $dir >/dev/null
        #git status -s | grep -c ^
        lnnum=$(git status -s | grep -c ^)
        #if [[ "$lnnum" != "0" ]]; then
        if (( $lnnum > 0 )); then
            echo $dir $lnnum
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Save this as a `.dart` file at the root of where you store all of your repositories.

Then, `dart run git.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args)
{
    print("");
    Run(".");
}

void Run(String path)
{
    for (var entity in Directory(path).listSync(recursive: false, followLinks: false))
    {
        if (entity.statSync().type != FileSystemEntityType.directory)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (!Directory(entity.path + Platform.pathSeparator + ".git").existsSync())
        {
            Run(entity.path);
            continue;
        }

        print("Looking At Repo: ${entity.path}");

        {
            var gitRemoteUpdateResult = Process.runSync('git', ['remote', 'update'], workingDirectory: entity.absolute.path);
            if (gitRemoteUpdateResult.exitCode != 0)
            {
                stderr.write(gitRemoteUpdateResult.stderr);
                return;
            }
        }

        var gitStatusResult = Process.runSync('git', ['status'], workingDirectory: entity.absolute.path);
        if (gitStatusResult.exitCode != 0)
        {
            stderr.write(gitStatusResult);
            return;
        }

        var gitStatusResultOut = gitStatusResult.stdout as String;

        if (
            !gitStatusResultOut.contains("nothing to commit, working tree clean") ||
            !gitStatusResultOut.contains("Your branch is up to date with"))
        {
            print("DIRTY");
        }

        print("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple program in C# that lists all the changed (but uncommitted) repos starting from D:\DEV

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("D:\\DEV", ".git", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string gitdir in directories)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(gitdir);
            DirectoryInfo dir = di.Parent;
            string resp = CommandOutput("git update-index --refresh", dir.FullName);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.Replace("\n","").Trim()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dir.FullName+" : ");
                Console.WriteLine(resp);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

public static string CommandOutput(string command, string workingDirectory )
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        if (null != workingDirectory)
        {
            procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        }

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        proc.OutputDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(e.Data);
        };
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(e.Data);
        };

        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        return string.Format("Error in command: {0}, {1}", command, objException.Message);
    }
}
}
```