# Find all .git repositories in the home directory and figure out which have uncommited changes and unpushed branches

Tags: git

This has been asked several times before,  but I don't see any satisfactory answers.  I am looking for a way to:

- Find all git repositories in the home directory
- For each repository display branches that are behind the remote
- Branches that do not have any remote counterparts
- Repositories that don't have any remotes
- Any uncommitted changes

There are pieces of that do some of these tasks,  but I don't see anything that is comprehensive.  I am about to start a github project that will do this,  but I want to find out if there is an existing tool that does all of the above.

Comment: I'm writing scripts to extract data out of Git (none of the above, mind you) and find that running `git` commands via `exec` in PHP is more than enough. I use Git to help with formatting where it can (`git log --oneline` for example) and then ordinary string manipulation to parse the output.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me for
[2 years](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/commit/a01fe1e)

```sh
for rp in ~/*/
do
  printf '\ec'
  cd "$rp"
  git status
  echo "${rp%/}"
  read
done
```

[git: Find all uncommited locals repos in a directory tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/961101/#9493518)

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/5339520/scripts/git-status.sh)