# maintain, cleanup, compress large number of git repositories in Ubuntu

Tags: git

By going through the below git documentation, I learned how to maintain, cleanup, compress and save space for a git repository. But the problem I am facing is, having a large number of git repositories, say around ( 500 ) of them, Its not easy to visit each repository and do these clean up things, is there an automated way to visit each repository and clean up or compress each repository ?

a shell script or something like that ?

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a shell script or something like that ?

There is nothing in Git itself for managing *multiple* repos, so yes, you would need to script the process you are currently doing for one repo.

See for instances the approaches taken in:

- "[How to quickly find all git repos under a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11981716/6309)
- "[git: Find all uncommited locals repos in a directory tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/961101/6309)"

Once you can find all your repos, you can apply the same set of commands you are currently using for one repo to compress and optimize said repo.